# Reformulation - Probability of correctly inferring whether a coin can produce heads

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, inference, binomial-distribution

[This is a repost, since the original post specified a slightly different problem than I actually had in mind]

Suppose you have a coin which you know could be biased towards tails with unknown probability $p_{\mathrm{t}}\ge0.5$. Your task is to find out whether the coin *can produce heads at all*.

To do so, you are allowed to make $n$ observations of coin flips. You observe $k$ times heads. If $k>0$, you conclude that the coin can produce heads. If $k=0$, you randomly guess with equal probability for "can produce heads" and "can not produce heads".

Given your single experiment of $n$ observations, you are now asked to provide an estimate $\hat{p}(\mathrm{correct})$ of the probability of having made a correct response such that for a large number of experiments your estimate would approach your objective performance for *any given true* $p_\mathrm{t}$.

A response is termed 'correct' when you say the coin can produce heads and indeed this is the case (i.e. $p_{\mathrm{t}} < 1$) or when you say the coin cannot produce heads and indeed $p_{\mathrm{t}} = 1$.

Objectively, the proportion correct (I think) is

$
p(\mathrm{correct}) = 1 - p(\mathrm{incorrect}) = 1 - 0.5\cdot p_{\mathrm{t}}^n
\tag{1}
$

In other words, I can be wrong only when all coin flips give a tail, and even then, I'm only wrong with a probability of 0.5.

Here's how I approached the problem so far. I thought, to approximate $p(\mathrm{correct})$, the observer has to make an estimate $\hat{p}_{\mathrm{t}}$ of the probability for tails.

I have thought of different ways of how the observer could estimate $\hat{p}_{\mathrm{t}}$:

a) The simplest estimate for $p_{\mathrm{t}}$ would be to just count the number of tails and divide by $n$, which gives:

$
\hat{p}(\mathrm{correct}) = 1-0.5\cdot(1-\frac{k}{n})^n
\tag{2}
$

b) You could use the knowledge that the probability distribution for $p_{\mathrm{t}}$ given $n-k$ observations of tails is given by the Beta distribution:

$
f(p_{\mathrm{t}}) = \mathrm{Beta}(p_{\mathrm{t}}; n-k+1, k+1)
$

We can then compute the full integral:

$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{p}(\mathrm{correct}) = 1-0.5\cdot \int\limits_{p_\mathrm{t}=0}^1 \mathrm{Beta}(p_{\mathrm{t}}; n-k+1, k+1)\cdot p_{\mathrm{t}}^n = \\
1-0.5\cdot\frac{1}{\mathrm{B}(n-k+1, k+1)}\int\limits_{p_\mathrm{t}=0}^1 p_\mathrm{t}^{n-k} (1-p_\mathrm{t})^k \,p_\mathrm{t}^n =\\
1-0.5\cdot\frac{1}{\mathrm{B}(n-k+1, k+1)}\int\limits_{p_\mathrm{t}=0}^1 p_\mathrm{t}^{2n-k} (1-p_\mathrm{t})^k =\\
1-0.5\cdot\frac{\mathrm{B}(2n-k+1, k+1)}{\mathrm{B}(n-k+1, k+1)} =
1-0.5\cdot \frac{(2n-k)!(n+1)!}{(2n+1)!(n-k)!}
\end{aligned}
\tag{3}
$

c) Realizing that the distribution of $p_{\mathrm{t}}$ is given by a Beta distribution, we could also use the mean of the distribution rather than the mode (which would be equivalent to a)). Since the mean of a Beta distribution is given by $\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+\beta-2}$, we arrive at:

$
\hat{p}(\mathrm{correct}) = 1-0.5\cdot(1-\frac{k+1}{n+2})^n
\tag{4}
$

---

However, all approaches mis-estimate $p(\mathrm{correct})$. And indeed, intuitively it might seem impossible to provide an estimate of $p(\mathrm{correct})$ that is unbiased for all underlying values of $p_\mathrm{t}$. For instance, when true $p_\mathrm{t}=1$, it must be $p(\mathrm{correct})=0.5$ since I will always only observe tails (i.e. $k=0$). However, when $k=0$, my formulas (except a), but a) has other problems) will have results above 0.5 – and rightfully so from their perspective, because $k=0$ in one instance of the experiment does not imply $k=0$ in every other experiment.

So my question is then: is it indeed impossible to provide an unbiased estimate of $p(\mathrm{correct})$ for any true $p_\mathrm{t}$, such that in the long run, the average of my estimates $\hat{p}(\mathrm{correct})$ would approach the true $p(\mathrm{correct})$? Or would it be possible to provide an appropriate correction to my estimates?

Also I think (in hindsight) that my approach taken with a), b), c) will actually not lead to the solution that I have in mind. I think what it would take would be a full model of the expected performance for any true $p_\mathrm{t}$ and then kind of invert the model to provide a $\hat{p}(\mathrm{correct})$ that would converge to the $p(\mathrm{correct})$. At the moment though I have no idea how to approach this.

**Edit:**
Well, there's one 'trivial' solution, which is:

$$
\hat{p}(\mathrm{correct}) = 
\begin{cases}
0.5 & \text{if $k=0$}\\
1 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

This estimate would actually be unbiased. But it would also not be an interesting estimate for my purpose since it is not a sufficiently "graded" estimate of $p(\mathrm{correct})$. But maybe this is the answer? There is no unbiased estimate that is also graded?

It seems like this. An unbiased estimate for $p_\mathrm{t}=1$ requires that I set $\hat{p}(\mathrm{correct})=0.5$. However, if this hard rule should not lead to an understimation for all other $p_\mathrm{t}$, I must set $\hat{p}(\mathrm{correct})=1$ in literally every other case. So there is no 'wiggle room' for more graded estimates.